# Unity ads Advertisements.Advertisement defined multiple times error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ads

I upgraded to Unity ads 2.1.0 from the previously released version (2.0) and changed nothing in my code; However, now I am getting an error that says that what I am "using", Advertisement namespace, is defined multiple times. I am not sure why this error would occur if I have not changed anything. The unity ads documentation has not been changed either.

This is the only class with ad code inside of it. Is this a problem with the code or with the assets within the Unity project? My code that includes my Advertisement namespace is below.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class AdsController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int adCount;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        adCount = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Play Ad", 0) + 1;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Play Ad", adCount);

        while (Advertisement.IsReady() != true)
        {
            Debug.Log("Waiting for ad..)");
        }

        if (Advertisement.IsReady() && adCount >= 5)
        {
            Advertisement.Show();
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Play Ad", 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you have the unity ads asset package and also you have it enabled in services tab?

Comment: @Lestat It has been enabled yes. And what do you mean by me having the unity ads asset package?

Comment: you can add ads ith the asset package or with the services tab, but not both